# How does one print text at the beginning of a line without overwriting existing input text?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, printing

I have been trying to make a multithreaded chat server and client in Python, and it's all going quite well, except for one thing. I have two threads, one for sending messages, and another for receiving and printing messages, as shown below.

```python
class SendThread(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def run(self):
        global s
        try:
            while s:
                time.sleep(0.2)  
                data = input("\r")
                s.send(data.encode("ASCII"))
        except:
            print("An exception occurred, terminating!")
            s.close()

class RecvThread(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def run(self):
        global s
        try:
            while s:
                recv = s.recv(4096)
                if recv:
                    print("\r" + recv.decode("ASCII"), flush=True)
                else:
                    s.close()
                    print("You have disconnected from the server!")
        except:
            print("An exception occurred, terminating!")
            s.close()
```

The issue is when a person is typing a message to send, and receives a message sent by another connected client, the message currently being typed in disappears, but is still there in the sense that it is still being stored.

What I want to happen is for the message being received to be displayed on the same line the input is on, then for a newline to be printed after it so the input text is visible on the next line:

```python
# before other client(s) send a message

User1: hello!
Me: hi!
how are you?                           # currently being typed

# after other client(s) send a message

User1: hello!
Me: hi!
User1: are you alright?
how are you? good?                     # still being typed

# when the current user sends the message

User1: hello!
Me: hi!
User1: are you alright?
Me: how are you? good?                 # sent message
i'm fine,                              # new input being typed
```

Right now, the output is:

```python
# before other client(s) send a message

User1: hello!
Me: hi!
how are you?                           # currently being typed

# after other client(s) send a message

User1: hello!
Me: hi!
User1: are you alright?
good?                                  # still being typed

# when the current user sends the message

User1: hello!
Me: hi!
User1: are you alright?
Me: how are you? good?                 # sent message
i'm fine,                              # new input being typed
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't think that this is possible due to the nature of command line consoles. Funnily enough, I've also recently developed a simple chat program. I tried console first, but then moved to tkinter. In tkinter, I solved the problem by having an output textbox and an input textbox

Comment: You'd have to keep track of what's currently being typed in and when a new message comes in, print the new message and the reprint the text that was being typed. You probably need to add some kind of coordinating logic in your main thread.

Comment: I imagine ncurses could accommodate this (input box at the bottom)

Comment: What is the global `s`? A socket?

Comment: @Yardid I was just thinking of that. I'm probably going to go the GUI way, thanks anyhow. @jonatan I want it to be cross-platform, and the documentation says that the Windows version of Python doesn't come with it standard, and UniCurses must be used, which is external. @Wyatt `s` is a socket, the socket connected to the server.

Comment: prompt_toolkit (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/prompt_toolkit) has some facilities to improve console output when dealing with threads. See their examples.

Comment: Thanks for the help, everyone. I got a GUI version working, and it's pretty decent.